# Django: How do I pass different urls to a generic view?

Tags: django, url, variables

I'm building an app that is similar to an address book. For one of my views, I have a list of Individuals. Each `Individual` has a `Role` which links them to their job title and employer. There are several different types of employers so this is a generic relation.

Using the ListView generic view, I have created a list of individuals that displays their name, their job title and their employer, i.e.

> "Jimmy, Officer, Chase Bank"
>
> "Mary, CEO, General Hospital"

I need the names of the companies to be links that go to the companies detail page.

**The Problem**

Since I have one template for this list, I am having a hard time understanding how to change the url based on what type of employer the individual has i.e. Bank or Hospital.

**What Might Work**

1. Should I write a function for the view that takes the employer content type and creates a variable? Or should I put the function under the `Role` model? I am a noob to python/Django and am not sure how to even write this.
2. I attempted to use if/else statements in the template, i.e. if bank, use this url, but it did not work. Probably because it is a generic relation and my query was not right.

In response to the comment below:

I'm not sure exactly what you meant by inheritance structures but here are a simplified version of my models;

```
class Individual(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    staff = generic.GenericRelation('Role',
        content_type_field='employer_content_type',
        object_id_field='employer_id'
    )

   class Hospital(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    staff = generic.GenericRelation('Role',
        content_type_field='employer_content_type',
        object_id_field='employer_id'
    )
... and so on for each different employer

class Role(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    job_holder = models.ForeignKey(Individual)
    employer_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
        limit_choices_to={"model__in": ('venue', 'festival', 'artsorganization','bookingagent', 'managementcompany', 'mediaoutlet', 'otherorganization', 'presentercompany', 'publishingcompany', 'presenter', 'recordcompany', 'musician', 'ensemble')}, related_name="employer")
    employer_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    employer = generic.GenericForeignKey('employer_content_type', 'employer_id')
```

At one point I had all employers inheriting from a Company model. I changed it because each employer has different attributes which was making things very complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add how you defined the inheritance structure of your Employers?

Comment: Hi @dokkaebi I added my model structures in response to you comment. It gave me an idea! What if I made a Company model that each different type of company had a OneToOne Relationship to? Then the url could be the same and the detail page would just display the different information based on if statements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe each kind of employer should be responsible for providing a URL to itself (see [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)). That is, each employee model supplies `get_absolute_url` to determine a URL for itself.

Then, you can simply use (in your template):

```
{{ individual.name }}
<a href="{{ individual.role.employer.get_absolute_url }}">
  {{ individual.role.employer.name }}
</a>
```

It's simplified here since the "Role to Individual" relation is One-to-Many, but use whatever mechanism you use to determine the employer's name in this instance. If your list is of roles, you obviously just use `role.employer` and instead `role.job_holder` to get the individual etc.